# Enviar datos POST con orange pi

Tags: linux, http-post, raspbian

Estoy intentando mandarme una serie de datos a mi base de datos que tengo en un servidor, y pensé en utilizar una orange pi one, que es la que tengo por casa, y en el servidor he montado un web service en java spring, la idea seria que los datos que recoge la orange pi se los mande a mi servidor, primero en local obviamente, aunque también me gustaría que fuera online.

Tenia pensado utilizar una distribución de arch-linux, ya que encontré por google que puedo instalarlo de esta manera:

https://minibots.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/instalacion-basica-de-archlinux-en-orange-pi-one/

Aunque la verdad me daría igual que distribución usar, quiero la mas ligera de terminal que pueda encontrar, ya que solo necesito usar los GPIOs y ethernet.

Algún consejo? Que os parece? Utilizaríais otra distribución? Si me pudierais decir también un poco como realizar lo del ethernet que es lo que mas me come la cabeza se agradecería.

Muchas gracias por leerme y aconsejarme( si posteais algo :P )

Saludos.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con lo de ethernet? ¿A la comunicación entre Orange Pi y backend?

Comment: A la comunicacion de la orange pi, enviandole datos por POST a un web service que tengo en mi servidor.

Comment: ¿Qué lenguajes conoces? ¿Con cuál te sientes más cómodo?

Comment: Perdona Sema, estuve muy liado ayer, me siento cómodo con casi todos, la verdad me gustaría realizarlo con java, por no cambiar de lenguaje con respecto al web service del servidor, pero me daría igual el lenguaje. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Si te sientes cómodo con Java, no tengas miedo y adelante, hazlo en Java, te permitirá centrarte en la idea y no preocuparte por el lenguaje, pues ya lo conoces y dominas.

Lo que tendrás que desarrollar será una librería (.jar) que será invocada por línea de comandos, y donde le pasarás los parámetros o argumentos que quieras enviar al servidor mediante POST:

```
java -jar MyClient.jar param1 param2
```

Si quieres enviar por ejemplo las medidas de los sensores de humedad y oxígeno sería algo parecido a:

```
java -jar MyClient.jar "oxigeno:27" "humedad:49"
```

De esta forma, tu clase principal sería parecido a esto:

```
public class MyClient {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(String s: args) {
      System.out.println("Lectura sensor recibida: " + s);
    }
  }
}
```

Después de eso, deberías coger cada argumento y hacer un split(":"), que te devolverá un array, para así conocer qué sensor estás operando (posición 0) y qué valor has medido/recibido de ese sensor (posición 1).

Una vez hecho eso, ya puedes volcar tus datos donde necesites, como por ejemplo, una base de datos.

Espero haber podido aclararte la duda

Comment: Por ahora, me lo has dejado cristalino, empezare este fin de semana a programarlo a ver si soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar, ten claro que si me surge alguna duda vendré a preguntar jejeje Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Esa es la idea, ayudar y compartir. Vuelve si tienes algún problema, comunidad somos todos. Marca si eres tan amable la respuesta como correcta para que pueda servir a más usuarios que tengan una duda similar.